# Restrict parsys in a static template to include only certain components without using etc/design (AEM)

Tags: aem

I am using `AEM 6.5` and I have a `static` template that contains a `parsys` -

```
<header class="wrapper">
    <div data-sly-resource="${'mypar' @ resourceType='wcm/foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
</header>
```

I want to restrict this parsys so that only a particular component (say `Comp1`) can be added.
I know that I can add this can be configured under `etc/designs/<app-name>/<template-name>/mypar` with a property `components`. The problem in my case is that the pages that use this template do not have a design associated with it. I dont want to create a new design just for this one property.

Is there and alternative to restrict a parsys or a static template to use only certain components. I need to make this as a prt of my code base.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library wcm.io, which includes a parsys that can be configured in the parent-component. https://wcm.io/wcm/parsys/usage.html This library is maintained by one of the biggest AEM agencies in Germany.

An alternative is to create your own parsys component.